# Why am I getting string does not name a type Error?

Tags: c++, string, std

#### game.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "game.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "piece.h"

using namespace std;
```

#### game.h

```cpp
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include <string>

class Game
{
    private:
        string white;
        string black;
        string title;
    public:
        Game(istream&, ostream&);
        void display(colour, short);
};

#endif
```

---

The error is:

> `game.h:8 error: 'string' does not name a type`
>   `game.h:9 error: 'string' does not name a type`

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Your `using` declaration is in `game.cpp`, not `game.h` where you actually declare string variables. You intended to put `using namespace std;` into the header, above the lines that use `string`, which would let those lines find the `string` type defined in the `std` namespace.

As [others have pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527665/weird-string-does-not-name-a-type-error-c/5527754#5527754), this is [not good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) in headers -- everyone who includes that header will also involuntarily hit the `using` line and import `std` into their namespace; the right solution is to change those lines to use `std::string` instead

Comment: @Michael Mrozek, @Steven: Moving `using namespace std;` into the header is a despicable act. Advising it doubly-so!

Comment: @Johnsyweb Personally I hate `using namespace` altogether, but it's clearly what he intended to do

Comment: @Michael: All the more reason to discourage him!

Comment: From the book C++ Coding Standards (Sutter) - "Don't write namespace usings in a header file or before an #include" It is not about style but about danger.

Comment: @Johnsyweb I hate when I search the internet for a problem, see someone who's asked the same question, and all the answers are "no, don't do that" -- I answer the question that was asked. I should've mentioned that it's a bad idea, yes, but I refuse to just say "no, it's impossible"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Why don't you edit your answer to make it clear it is bad practice?

Comment: @Will [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527665/weird-string-does-not-name-a-type-error-c/5527754#5527754) already does, and I think my answer is beyond saving at this point, it's been downvoted too many times

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Since it is the accepted answer, I hesitate to delete.  Editing would appease the good-practices gods without destroying content.  Anyhow, you've gotten a total of 32 rep out of this, so it isn't all bad.  If you're *absolutely sure* you want to delete, I'll do it.

Comment: @Michael: Thank you for the edit. I hate searching the web for the solution to a problem only to find that the top hit is a hack. +1 :-)

Answer (score 50):

`string` does not name a type. The class in the `string` header is called `std::string`.

Please **do not** put `using namespace std` in a header file, it pollutes the global namespace for all users of that header. See also ["Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Your class should look like this:

```
#include <string>

class Game
{
    private:
        std::string white;
        std::string black;
        std::string title;
    public:
        Game(std::istream&, std::ostream&);
        void display(colour, short);
};
```

Comment: @Jonhsyweb: +1 for pointing out the perils of `using namespace`

Comment: should #include <string> also be included in the header file in addition to it being included in the main .cpp file?

Comment: @Gnuey: Since `#include <string>` is required for any compilation unit including this header, I would include that line, yes. There is no need to repeat this directive in any subsequent source file.

Answer (score 10):

Just use the `std::` qualifier in front of `string` in your header files.

In fact, you should use it for `istream` and `ostream` also - and then you will need `#include <iostream>` at the top of your header file to make it more self contained.

Answer (score 5):

Try a `using namespace std;` at the top of `game.h` or use the fully-qualified `std::string` instead of `string`.

The `namespace` in `game.cpp` is after the header is included.

Answer (score 4):

**You can overcome this error in two simple ways**

**First way**

```cpp
using namespace std;
include <string>
// then you can use string class the normal way
```

**Second way**

```cpp
// after including the class string in your cpp file as follows
include <string>
/*Now when you are using a string class you have to put **std::** before you write 
string as follows*/
std::string name; // a string declaration
```

Comment: Second way is the correct way. Don't muck up the namespace.