# Compile error C++

Tags: c++, string, compilation

I am new in C++. When I compile this code compiler reports error-

main.cpp-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "main.h"

using namespace std;

string strings::getstr(string str)
{
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    strings strstr;
    string constr;
    string msg;

    msg = "Hello World!";
    constr = strstr.getstr(msg);
    cout << constr;
    return 0;
}
```

main.h-

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_INCLUDED
#define MAIN_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class strings
{
public:
    string getstr (string str);
};

#endif // MAIN_H_INCLUDED
```

error-

```
error: 'string' does not name a type
error: no 'std::string strings::getstr(std::string)' member function declared in class 'strings'
error: In function 'int main()':
error: 'class strings' has no member named 'getstr'
```

I am using Code::Blocks and gcc
I have written this simple code because I am working on a project and when I want to compile I always getting

> 'string' does not name a type

sorry for bad english...

Comment: Use std::string instead of string. And std::cout instead of cout.

Comment: Check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c)

Comment: I would put an answer in but this absolutely has to be a duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527665/weird-string-does-not-name-a-type-error-c

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use `using namespace std;` after the header in `main.h`

Answer (score 0):

The correct name for the string class is 'std::string' because it is declared within the 'std' namespace (the same goes for 'cout'). After you change 'string' into 'std::string' and use 'std::cout' instead of 'cout' your program will compile correctly.

Another way to do it is to place 'std' the as the first namespace:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

Personally, I don't like to use 'using namespace ...' (It's difficult for me to keep track of different namespaces ).

Comment: `using namespace std` does not make `std` the "default" namespace (that concept doesn't exist in the language.) It is also a terrible idea to do that in a header file.

Answer (score -1):

This could fix the problem

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_INCLUDED
#define MAIN_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class strings
{
public:
    std::string getstr(std::string str);
};

#endif // MAIN_H_INCLUDED
```