# Unusual error with assigning string to variables

Tags: c++, string

I am having trouble assigning a string to a variable.  It should be

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string Name1 = "hello";
```

but when I compile this I get an error that string does not name a type.

Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird string does not name a type Error C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527665/weird-string-does-not-name-a-type-error-c)

Comment: Any more information to help reproduce this? I don't think the lines of code you've provided are a valid, compilable program as is. Wrapping it in a standard `int main` didn't yield any errors here: http://codepad.org/X7bmTmYs

Comment: thanks, but even that isn't working on my school's C++ compiler.  It works on codepad.org and other sites, so it must be something wrong with the compiler I'm using.

Comment: The code seems fine and should compile. Which compiler are you using? Can you paste the compiler output?

Comment: You have a compiler error. please give your compiler version and if at all possible a complete compilable example to reproduce the problem. As is your code doesn't compile on anything. You could also paste the exact compiler error output.

Comment: @LuciaPasarin if he has actually transcribed the code correctly then it is not a duplicate of that

Comment: @EricMorse you edited your code with a major change an hour after you posted it... please make sure you have posted the **exact code** which is giving the error. Don't make stuff up or try to go from memory.

Comment: it works now.  Thanks.  I was using the gcc to compile when I should've been using g++ to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C++, then you should add the `std` namespace in front of the type name like this

```
std::string
```

Or you could add `using namespace std;` before that line to make the contents of the std namespace usable directly.

Comment: The `using namespace std;` is a very poor recommendation.  Prefer to clarify and only use identifiers from `std` as necessary.  Try `using std::string;`