# Error with const member in class

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class named `Student` with its `Name` and `Address` classes.

```
#ifndef ADDRESS_H
#define ADDRESS_H
 //This is address class    
#include <string>

class Address{

public:
       Address(std::string street, std::string city, std::string state, std::string zip) : 
            street(street), city(city),state(state),zip(zip)
       {}
       std::string street,city,state,zip;
       std::string aString;    
       aString=street+city+state+zip;
//private:
};
#endif
```

and the `Name` class is

```
#ifndef NAME_H
#define NAME_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Name {
        friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const  Name &name) {
                if(name.middle!="")
                  os << name.last << ", "<<name.middle<<" ," << name.first;
                else
                  os<< name.last <<", "<<name.first;            

                return os;
        }
public:
        Name(std::string last, std::string middle, std::string first) : last(last), first(first),middle(middle) {}
private:
        std::string last, first, middle;
};

#endif
```

And the `Student` class is like:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "name.h"
#include "Address.h"

class Person {
        friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Person &person);
public:
        Person(const Name &name, int age, const Address &address);
        Address address;
        std::string adr=address.aString;
//private:
        Name name;
        int age;
};
#endif
```

Finally, to call them.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "student.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Person::Person(const Name &name, int age, const Address &address) : name(name), age(age),address(address) {}

ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, const Person &person) {
        os << person.name << " " << person.age<<person.adr;
        return os;
}

#include <iostream>

#include "student.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
        Person p(Name("Doe","","Jane"), 21, Address("Park Ave","New York","NY","10002"));
        Person p2(Name("Bane","IHateM","Jane"), 21, Address("Bay parkway","Brooklyn","NY","11223"));
        cout << p<<endl;
        cout<< p2<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

However, there are some errors during compilation. 
(1) The following line is wrong based on complier, how to fix it please?

```
std::string adr=address.aString;
```

(2) In my `address` class, the compiler said that "string does not name a type Error", but following this [Why am I getting string does not name a type Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527665/weird-string-does-not-name-a-type-error-c)  can't fix the problem, why is that?

Comment: You posted your `Address` class twice, and missed `Name`

Comment: Thank for reminding.I have fixed it.

Comment: It appears that you continued to write code after introducing this error; **never add to code that doesn't work.** It also appears that you are attempting a complicated exercise before you have mastered the basics. What do you expect the assignment (`std::string adr=address.aString;`) to do? When do you expect it to be executed?

Comment: @immibis - he changed the file, like I suggested in the first comment, but not the problem. It was a valid edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simple Solution

The simplest solution is to move your `aString=street+city+state+zip;` inside the `Address` constructor.

Do the same for your `adr = ...` statement (you'll still need a 'declaration' for `std::string adr;` within your class header).

#### To understand why what you wrote won't work, consider this:

When you write (within a class declaration, like in your header)

```
class myClass
{
    int a = 5;
};
```

you assign a default value to the `int a` that you have declared - this is both declaration and (default) assignment.

When you write

```
class Address{    
public:
       Address(std::string street, std::string city, std::string state, std::string zip) : 
           street(street), city(city),state(state),zip(zip)
       {}

       std::string street,city,state,zip;
       std::string aString;    
       aString=street+city+state+zip;
};
```

you're trying to give a default assignment to `aString`, but this is invalid code.

You could do this using

`std::string aString = ...;`

but not

```
std::string aString;
aString = ...;
```

because the last line is a 'statement' - something to be executed.