# problems about declaring a string in arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I have an problem with declaring a string.

> Arduino: 1.6.9 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>
> readBinaryCode:3: error: 'string' does not name a type
>
> ```
> string code = "10101010010010100101000101010101111100"
> ```
>
> C:\Users\Jerel\Desktop\All\Sketchs\readBinaryCode\readBinaryCode.ino:
>   In function 'void loop()':
>
> readBinaryCode:12: error: 'code' was not declared in this scope
>
> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {...
> ```
>
> exit status 1
>
> 'string' does not name a type

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: Try `std::string`. I've done the Zuul joke already once today. And make sure `<string>` is included.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird string does not name a type Error C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527665/weird-string-does-not-name-a-type-error-c)

Answer (score 0):

Its telling you the truth.

```
 'string' does not name a type
```

Instead of

```
 `string code` use  `String code`



 void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
    String code = "10101010010010100101000101010101111100";

    }
```

**Update**
we dont need any to include anything for this

Comment: I am extremely dubious about what you are suggesting. `string.h` is a C standard library header containing `strcpy` etc.  `string` is a C++ class template from `string`.  I've not programmed on the Arduino but I would be surprised if they hijacked a C library header and started stuffing it with classes that replicated what C++ does.

Comment: I got tht. we dont need that include statement. And yes you were right about the string.h. My bad.